# understanding decompiling assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, decompiling

I have the following code that I was to decompile:

```
movl $0x2feaf, -0x18(%ebp)
mov  0x8(%ebp), %eax
mov  %eax, -0x14(%ebp)
```

my problem is, I don't understand what 0x8(%ebp) means in the context. I tried the following c code:

```
int b = 196271;
int a = b;
```

but that gives me

```
movl $0x2feaf, -0x8(%ebp)
mov  -0x8(%ebp), $eax
mov  %eax, -0x4(%ebp)
```

what does 0x8(%ebp) mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means move whatever is at [EBP+8] into the EAX register.

In most contexts, [EBP+8] will be a parameter to the current function.